# Splitting groups as homogeneous as possible

Tags: algorithm, grouping

I have n groups. Number of items in each group is lets say c1,...,cn. I need to split it in k new groups of equal size (+/- d% deviation in size) so that I can minimize number of old groups in each new group, i.e. min[sum(c in each k)].

Do you have any idea how? Maybe some standard algorithm? Sorry for vague question. I would love to answer any questions on details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give a small example for the problem.

Comment: Do you want each new group to be formed from a minimal number of old groups, or do you want to spread out the old groups evenly among the new groups so that each new group has members from every old group? Also what is your objective function, i.e. how do you measure success? The maximum number of old groups contained in any one new group?

Comment: "each new group to be formed from a minimal number of old groups" - this one please :) but I have no idea how to measure success in this situation tbh

Answer (score 0):

Let the total number of people be m.  If the original groups are roughly the same size, this simple procedure should approximately minimise the maximum number of same-old-group people in any new group:

- If m/k is fractional, then some new groups will need to have 1 more person than the rest.  Let e = m - roundDown(m/k) * k.  There will be e 1-larger new groups, which we will (arbitrarily) choose first.
- Arrange people so that old groups form rows, and the rows are "left justified".  The order of rows, and of people within each row, doesn't matter.
- Add people to the first new group by starting in the top-left corner and going down the leftmost column.  If you get to the bottom and you still haven't picked roundDown(m/k)+1 people for this new group, continue at the top of the second column, etc.  If you get to a "hole" (because the row at this column position already finished somewhere to the left), just keep going down.  Basically this means that any two people from the same old group (row) who make it into the same new group are picked as far apart as possible.

  - Repeat this for the first e new groups.
  - For the remaining k - e new groups, do the same, but only pick roundDown(m/k) people for each.